# SQL query - how to display the most common value only

Tags: mysql, sql

I have recently started to learn sql queries but i am having some issues. 
I have these two tables here:

**Birds**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9slDt.png

**MembersLikesBirdEncounter** (birdID is the foriegn key here referenced from above table Birds)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv3O3.png

i am trying to display the most common birdID value from the table **MembersLikesBirdEncounter**, which is 234. Below is the query i have come up with which doesn't seem to be working. What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT      m.birdID, COUNT(m.birdID)  
FROM        MembersLikesBirdEncounter m, Birds b
WHERE       b.birdID = m.birdID
GROUP BY    m.birdID
ORDER BY    m.birdID DESC 
LIMIT       1;
```

I want the output to be

```
birdID
------
234
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so hard...

Instead:

```
     GROUP BY Count(m.birdID) DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input but i can't seem to get it work still??

Comment: i replaced the group by and order by statement with yours

Comment: Leave the grouping clause alone:  just change the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Then, the problem with your query is the `ORDER BY` column.  You want to order by the count:

```
SELECT m.birdID, COUNT(m.birdID)  
FROM MembersLikesBirdEncounter m JOIN
     Birds b
     ON b.birdID = m.birdID
GROUP BY m.birdID
ORDER BY COUNT(jm.birdID) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Then -- assuming that `birdId` refers always refers to valid birds -- the `JOIN` is not necessary.  This should be sufficient:

```
SELECT m.birdID, COUNT(m.birdID)  
FROM MembersLikesBirdEncounter m 
GROUP BY m.birdID
ORDER BY COUNT(jm.birdID) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. Is there any way to display only the birdID row? i do not want the system to display the count row too

Comment: @katetango . . . Just remove `COUNT(m.birdID)` from the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help